# Why is my code giving me an "infinity, 1/0 error"?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

```
    NDSolve[
 {D[(r ((D[u[r], r])^(1/2 ) + a^(1/2))^2), r] == r  Const, 
  u'[0.0001] == .00001, 
  u[1] == 0.00001},
 {u[r]}, {r, .00001, 1}
 ]
```

Whenever I try to run the above code Im receiving the error `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/Sqrt[0.] encountered.` Ive replaced the values that should be 0 with numbers close to zero to try to avoid this but it still wont work. Any advice on how I should proceed to solve this DE?

Comment: What is `Const` and `a`?

Comment: they are just 2 different constants they can be any non zero number

Comment: I do not get this error with arbitrary values for `a` and `Const`. But may be the values I used are not the same as you did. But instead of having people guess and ask, why not update your question and post a complete self contained code which include the constants you used?  Question should be self contained and should include all values used to make it work as is.

Comment: @Nasser I still get the error, what options and values have you used? Just for checking

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I left it running for  like 10 minutes then gave up and stopped it.  It seems to hang. this is what I used. `ClearAll[u,r];
a=1;
const=2;
ode=D[(r ((D[u[r],r])^(1/2)+a^(1/2))^2),r]==r*const;
ic={u'[0.0001]==.00001,u[1]==0.00001};
NDSolve[{ode,ic},u[r],{r,.00001,1}]` I'll try later and wait more. But if this something that is suppoed to take looong time, this also should be mentioned in the question, to alert someone that it it takes long time.

Comment: @Nasser, simplifying the DE, and `a=Const=2` I run over several minutes `NDSolve[{3 Sqrt[Derivative[1][u][r]] + 2 Sqrt[3] Derivative[1][u][r] +Derivative[1][u][r]^(3/2) + Sqrt[3] r (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] + r Sqrt[Derivative[1][u][r]] (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] ==  2 Sqrt[Derivative[1][u][r]] r, u'[0.0001] == 0.0001,  u[1] == 0}, u, {r, .0001, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 10]`. No way, the error persists, but return a solution. Something wrong with the DE at `r=0`.

Comment: is it your intention do have a condition at a point not on the domain boundary?  ( `0.0001` vs `0.00001` )

Comment: The equation is troublesome because the derivative goes negative then the second derivative becomes complex. (Actually since `u'=u''=0` is a solution you might just use `WhenEvent` to stop when `u'==0`.  This is actually a first order equation in the first derivative by the way.

Comment: For one run with random parameters I got: `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/Sqrt[0.] encountered.`. Your denominator is `Sqrt[u'[r]]`. So the error is generated when `u'[r] == 0`. @george2079's suggestion using `WhenEvent` should fix that. For other parameter values it seems to hang.

Comment: Change u'[r] to v[r] and use DSolve

Answer (score 2):

Since we only have derivatives in u, we can convert the ode to

```
ode = D[(r ((D[u[r], r])^(1/2) + a^(1/2))^2), r] == r Const;
```

Let `u'[r] -> v[r]` by

```
ode=ode /. u -> (Integrate[v[#], r] &)
(* (r (Sqrt[a]+Sqrt[v[r]]) \
(v^\[Prime])[r])/Sqrt[v[r]]+(Sqrt[a]+Sqrt[v[r]])^2==Const r*)

vsol = DSolve[ode, v[r], r] // Flatten;
```

We get 2 solutions and it is difficult to tell offhand which one we want.

```
 v1[r_] = v[r] /. vsol[[1]] /. C[1] -> c1
 v2[r_] = v[r] /. vsol[[2]] /. C[1] -> c3
(* (-(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 a c1 r^3+a Const r^5])+2 a r^2+2 c1 r+Const r^3)/(2 r^2) *)

(* (2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 a c3 r^3+a Const r^5]+2 a r^2+2 c3 r+Const r^3)/(2 r^2) *)
```

Anything useful from the constants at r = 0 ?

```
Limit[v1[r], r -> 0]
Limit[v2[r], r -> 0]
(* c1 Infinity *)
(* c3 Infinity *)
```

Remember that the v[r] are the u'[r] and we can only get finite solutions of u'[r] at r = 0 by setting

```
c1=0;
c3=0;

v1[r_] = v1[r] // PowerExpand // Apart
v2[r_] = v2[r] // PowerExpand // Apart

(* -(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] Sqrt[Const] Sqrt[r])+a+(Const r)/2 *)

(* Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] Sqrt[Const] Sqrt[r]+a+(Const r)/2 *)

v1[0]
v2[0]
(* a *)
(* a *)
```

I still don't know which solution is better, but there will be a problem with NDSolve that doesn't have as one of the conditions `u'[0]==a`.  Now get u[r] with

```
u1[r_] = Integrate[v1[r], r] + c2
u2[r_] = Integrate[v2[r], r] + c4

(* -(1/3) (2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] Sqrt[Const] r^(3/2))+a r+c2+(Const r^2)/4 *)

(* 2/3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] Sqrt[Const] r^(3/2)+a r+c4+(Const r^2)/4 *)

c2 = c2 /. Solve[u1[1] == 0, c2][[1]] // Simplify;
c4 = c4 /. Solve[u2[1] == 0, c4][[1]] // Simplify;

u1[r]
u2[r]

(* -(1/3) (2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] Sqrt[Const] r^(3/2))+2/3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] Sqrt[Const]+a r-a+(Const r^2)/4-Const/4 *)

(* 2/3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] Sqrt[Const] r^(3/2)-2/3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] Sqrt[Const]+a r-a+(Const r^2)/4-Const/4 *)
```

Probably need to know more about the physical problem to choose which solution.  It is interesting that it seems we don't get a choice about `u'[0]`.